# How to disable comments in YouTube API v3

Tags: json, rest, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We were uploading videos and disabling comments in YouTube v2 via the access control elements:

```
<yt:accessControl action="list" permission="denied"/>
<yt:accessControl action="comment" permission="denied"/>
<yt:accessControl action="rate" permission="denied"/>
```

But now we have to migrate to v3 APIs and I do not see a way to accomplish the same thing.
I only see the following fields that are updatable:

```
snippet.title
snippet.description
snippet.tags[]
snippet.categoryId
status.embeddable
status.license
status.publicStatsViewable
status.publishAt
status.privacyStatus
recordingDetails.locationDescription
recordingDetails.location.latitude
recordingDetails.location.longitude
recordingDetails.recordingDate
```

I do not see what the description for these fields are but the fields in the status part look promising but I don't know what valid values are for those fields.

Is it possible to disable comments and ratings in the version 3 API?

Comment: It wasn't clear to me at first but a description of valid values for video are on the video subcategory here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disabling comments and ratings on a video is not supported by the v3 API at this time.  There is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6194) where if you disable comments on your videos in your channel preferences and then upload a video through the v3 API, comments are still allowed on the video (note that this bug was reported internally, but it does not appear to have been fixed).  YouTube is still working out these features for v3.

Comment: I wish they wouldn't force us to switch over until there is feature parity between the old and new versions. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I have converted to API V3. Now, I have to go in to the Video Manager every time a video is uploaded to disable comments. Using API V2, my upload program disabled comments automatically. 

Please go to [Issue 473](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=473) and click the star to vote to have this feature restored to API V3.

Comment: Google developers have migrated the issue list to GitHub. Subscribe to updates about the Comments issue here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/473#thread-subscription-status

Comment: Google developers closed this issue because it was in the wrong place. I reposted the request to disable comments here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=7664
Please click the star to vote for this feature.

Comment: The Youtube API V3 seems like it has a few glaring bugs in general, which sucks for automation purposes. For example 'Set as Premiere' option, 'Disable Comments' and 'Disable Live Chat' are all examples of options that currently does not seem possible to achieve via the API. This is still the case as of Mar 2022 it seems.