# YouTube Api - Setting access controls for a new video (equivalent API V2)

Tags: .net, vb.net, youtube-api

I use the Youtube .Net Api V3. I didn't find parameters to disallow comments, rating. I saw that the Youtube Api V2 have access control parameters to do this. (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos#Setting_Access_Controls)

I try also to disallow embeding options but it doesn't seem to work.

```
Dim videoStatus As New VideoStatus
With videoStatus
  .Embeddable = False
  .PrivacyStatus = "private"
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this functionality is not yet available in API v3. See this issue item: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=473

Also, similar question on SO:
[How to disable comments in YouTube API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440460/how-to-disable-comments-in-youtube-api-v3)

Comment: Thanks, you comfirm that i believe. Have you an idea for the Embedding options ? Do you have the same issue ?

Comment: In theory the code you have above should work for embedding although I know there are some issues: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6557 and also with the updating of that field: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4861. Might be worth trying to update after the upload. Also, what is the value of status.embeddable on the returned VideoResource?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just try to set this options after the upload, but it doesn't work anymore.