# Can I disable YouTube live chat by API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want create new live streams from my application, but I don't want to use live chat. I don't found the possibility how can I turn it off during creation new event.

I tried to pass an empty string or `null` to `snippet.liveChatId`, but without success.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#snippet.liveChatId

Can I turn off chat through API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `snippet.liveChatId` is a String returned from the server and cannot be set.  It does not appear the YouTube Live Streaming API supports disabling chat at this time.  You will have to manually disable chat from the Live Event's control room.

Comment: See also: [linked issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29463431/10237506). **Note:** please vote for this feature in the linked [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35175046) - also mentioned in the comments of the SO post I've linked.