# Enabling and disabling comments on youtube video through api

Tags: youtube-api, comments

How do you enable/disable comments on a video using the YouTube api? Basically what's the api way of doing this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440460/how-to-disable-comments-in-youtube-api-v3), disabling comments and ratings on a video is not supported by the v3 API at this time.

> There is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6194) where if you disable comments on your videos in your channel preferences and then upload a video through the v3 API, comments are still allowed on the video (note that this bug was reported internally, but it does not appear to have been fixed). YouTube is still working out these features for v3.