# Disable Comments using the Youtube API in C#

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is there a way through the YouTube api using C# to set comments and Ratings? Specifically set to Disable Comments and Uncheck Show how many viewers like and dislike this video. All of the information about this is a bug in V3 seems to be 3-4 years old or older.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable comments in YouTube API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440460/how-to-disable-comments-in-youtube-api-v3)

Answer (score 1):

The YouTube Data API v3 does not support disabling comments.

Comment: Dam right. it's still the case as of Mar 2022. [Here's](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35174729) the issue to **star** or vote for.